# LabelEncoder specify classes in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I’m applying a LabelEncoder to a pandas DataFrame, `df`

```
Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat5
  A      A      A      A      E
  B      B      C      C      E
  C      D      C      C      E
  D      A      C      D      E
```

I'm applying a label encoder to a dataframe like this -

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
intIndexed = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

This is how the labels are mapped

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = 2
D = 3
E = 0
```

I'm guessing that `E` isn't given the value of `4` as it doesn't appear in any other column other than `Feat 5` .

I want `E` to be given the value of `4` - but don't know how to do this in a DataFrame.

Comment: You could use `df.replace({'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 4})`?

Comment: I would use replace too. Label encoder is a bit too much

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.fit) the label encoder and later [`transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.transform) the labels to their normalized encoding as follows:

```
In [4]: from sklearn import preprocessing
   ...: import numpy as np

In [5]: le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

In [6]: le.fit(np.unique(df.values))
Out[6]: LabelEncoder()

In [7]: list(le.classes_)
Out[7]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

In [8]: df.apply(le.transform)
Out[8]: 
   Feat1  Feat2  Feat3  Feat4  Feat5
0      0      0      0      0      4
1      1      1      2      2      4
2      2      3      2      2      4
3      3      0      2      3      4
```

---

One way to specify labels by default would be:

```
In [9]: labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

In [10]: enc = le.fit(labels)

In [11]: enc.classes_                       # sorts the labels in alphabetical order
Out[11]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
      dtype='<U1')

In [12]: enc.transform('E')
Out[12]: 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nickil, but this has changed the mapping to A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 0. Can I specify what values I want ?

Comment: Yes, you can specify the labels that needs to be encoded *[see edited answer]*. But the`LabelEncoder` sorts them internally and returns the sorted list.

Comment: Is there a way to put this into a pipeline?

Answer (score 6):

You can fit and transform in single statement,
Please find the code for encoding single column and assigning back to data frame.

```
df[columnName] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[columnName])
```