# Building a classification model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some students data with 1500 rows and 30 columns. i have used `GradientBoostingClassifier`. All the data is categorical and in the range of 0-80 and 0-90 categories.

I need to build an prediction model to predict if the student will fail and pass. columns 'Status' is my target variable. below is the code i have used

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data=data.apply(le.fit_transform)

X=data.copy()
y=data['Status']
# Import train_test_split function
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Split dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
#Import Gradient Boosting Classifier model
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
gb = GradientBoostingClassifier()
gb.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = gb.predict(X_test)
```

below is my model performance.

```
Accuracy: 0.9719317419707395
Precision: 0.9090272918124562
Recall: 0.5650282731622445
```

Please let me know what should I do to improve the model and how to handle the wide range of categorical data. Also when I am testing the model on different dataset, most of the time the categories are changing either due to spelling mistake or new addition

```
std_id  std_name Dem secn_id location bucket Primary_subject status
144     amy      SEP 5.3     P        dev    english         pass
230     mani     SEV 11.3    E        Tech   math            fail
299     sam      DE  5.1     nap      prac   science         pass
568     samy     SEP 1.1     P        prac   V1              pass
769     elle     SEP 1.2     pe       prac   english         pass
761     tanj     SEP 1.3     N        tech   V2              pass
112     jon      ERM 3.0     N        prac   phy             fail
116     pal      NAN 9.1     sc       etc    V1V2            pass
116     pal      NAN 9.2     sc       etc    V1V3            fail
113     josh     NAN 9.3     du       etc.   erp             fail
100     sug      EVV 9.1     sc       NAN    che             pass
323     adi      ERP 3.1     NAN      fit    math            fail
323     adi      ERP 3.2     NAN      fit    math            fail
```

this is how my input data looks like.For missing value i have replaced it with string "NAN". There are duplicate records for student if they have changed any option.

Comment: accuracy 0.97 and you need to improve?

Comment: Can you add the Prec, Recall for both class

Comment: though the accuracy is 0.97. when i use a new set of data, transform it and fit in this model it gives very wrong predictions

Answer (score 1):

Your model performance is decent. 
To improve further

1. **Tune the parameteres** of `GradientBoostingClassifier` . You can set values for parameters like `n_estimators`, `learning_rate` etc and check the performance of your model.
   For this task I'll suggest [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)
2. **Feature Engineering**: You can create new features from the existing ones. As you have not provided data it's hard to suggest anything. You can check the feature importance by using `Random Forest` etc and use features with high importance.
3. You can try **different algorithms** like `XGBoost`, `LightGBM` or even `neural network`
4. You can use cross-validator like [Stratified ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)

Regarding your next problem.

Again it's hard to suggest anything without looking at any data. 
To avoid spelling mistakes you can enforce users to select values from dropdown etc.
If that's not the case you can look at the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) library which will find the closest match of your category.

Comment: i am trying to test this model on a different dataset. but while doing the label encoding for the categories value. i see discrepancy. like after doing encoding for data, column 'location' P value was converted to 1. but when i did the label encoding on data_new, column ' location' P was converted to 3. please let me know will this impact the performance of the model and how to fix this issue.

Comment: You can predefined your categories and use them. So value of P will always be 1. See 2 nd part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893374/labelencoder-specify-classes-in-dataframe)

Comment: i tried the above mentioned link. modified it a bit and created my own encoding in dict using names = (np.unique(df.values))
ran = len(np.unique(df.values))
my_enc = dict(zip( names, range(ran+1)))
df.replace(my_enc, inplace=True). using this i have fixed the discrepancy. but length of my unique values is 115. so i have numbers from 0 to 115. i wonder if this will cause issue?? as the model may consider hierarchy like 115>93>45 etc and so on. any suggestions  on this??

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest to start with some data cleaning and data analysis.
The fact that your categories change due to mistakes need to be fixed in a preprocessing step. Here there are no too many shortcuts, you need to inspect and fix the data manually.

Check also the presence of missing value. If there are missing value you need to address also this issue. You can remove the samples (accepting the loss of information) or substitute the missing value with the average value for the specific feature. There exist other methods in the literature but as first step those two could do.

Please consider to check the number of samples that you have in each class. If the two classes are strongly unbalanced you could consider to look for solution that address "unbalanced data".

Classifier as Decision Trees/Random Forest are good option when handling categorical variables.

The use of a cross-validation to tune the hyper-parameter of the classifier could also improve the performance.

EDIT (after the add of the data table)

Probably you don't want to use the name of the students since that feature is not related to the success/ failure of the exam.

Comment: great. You have covered the topics that I missed in my answer :-)